# Disabled bootstrap-duallistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been testing [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) and its fantastic, but I was wondering how to disable the bootstrap-dual listbox at the beginning:

so I have:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" class="dual-list" disabled>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

after call: `$(".dual-list").bootstrapDualListbox();` the dual list is not disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the comments section of the link you posted:

> There is no built-in support for disable, so you need to disable the
>   proper elements by selecting them by hand, something like that:
>
> ```
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]_helper1"]').prop('disabled', true);
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]_helper2"]').prop('disabled', true);
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').parent().find('.moveall').prop('disabled',true);
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').parent().find('.move').prop('disabled',true);
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').parent().find('.removeall').prop('disabled',true);
> $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').parent().find('.remove').prop('disabled',true);
> ```
>
> :) .. Well, I was managing this via this one line instead of 6 or 7. A
>   property would have been cleaner. Thanks though
>
> ```
>     $(".bootstrap-duallistbox-container").find("*").prop("disabled",true);
> ```

via [István Ujj-Mészáros](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/#comment-1364913333) and [WorkerBee](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/#comment-1365171187)